# Is my substitution correct?

Tags: integration

I have to solve $$\int_{0}^{1}x^5\arcsin{x}dx$$.

I substituted $$\arcsin x= t$$
I got,

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}t\sin^5t\;\cos t\;dt$$
How do I go further? And is this correct substitution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This substitution is correct, but I think it complicates the problem. I think the better way would be to try [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) from the start.

Comment: Ok!but wouldn't integration by parts would be too long? Plus, I have been asked to do it by substitution so...

Comment: See the answer given by user1337 below. Also this substitution would have been helpful if it simplified the problem, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

What about integration by parts?

\begin{align*}
\int x^{5}\arcsin(x)\mathrm{d}x = \frac{x^{6}\arcsin(x)}{6} - \frac{1}{6}\int\frac{x^{6}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

Then your problem is reduced to solve the last integral.

This can be done through the substitution $x = \sin(t)$:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{x^{6}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\mathrm{d}x = \int\sin^{6}(t)\mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Ok! I got it! So I have to substitute after by parts. Thank you so much!!

Comment: You are welcome ! I am glad to be of help.