# What should I substitute?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^5\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}}dx$$
Should I substitute $$x=\sqrt{\cos2u}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, clarify where your square root ends.

Comment: If this question is linked to your other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4069035/is-my-substitution-correct), please tell us. This is in line with the advice given at [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

For $$F(n)=\int_0^1 x^{2n+1}\sqrt{\dfrac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}}\ dx$$

set $x^2=\cos2t\implies2x\ dx=-2\sin2t\ dt,0\le2t\le\dfrac\pi2$

$x=1\implies t=0,x=`0\implies t=\dfrac\pi4$

$\sqrt{\dfrac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}}=+\cot t$

$$F(2)=-\int_{\pi/4}^0\cos^22t\cot t\sin 2t\ dt$$

$$=-\int_{\pi/4}^0(1+\cos4t)\cos^2t\ dt$$

$$=\int_0^{\pi/4}\dfrac{(1+\cos4t)(1+\cos2t)}2\ dt\text{ as }\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=-\int_b^af(x)\ dx$$

Use  [Werner Formulas](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html) to complete the assignment

Comment: Thank you so much!!